# Will the ISP know what sites I visit if I use a VPN?

Tags: privacy, vpn

If I use a VPN, and visit any site on HTTPS, will the ISP know what sites I have visited? Because IP-addresses of websites are not encrypted?

And if the answer is yes, are there any ways to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

In short, **No**!

They see the **IP of the VPN service** and probably log it, and all your traffic including URL's IPs to your sites are encrypted. But if the VPN service is not encrypted, then the ISP could in theory can see all your traffic.

However, if you are using a `split tunneling` mode, then the ISP can see your DNS queries and surfing traffic.

Read more about VPN, and be sure what mode you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Which ISP do you mean?
ISP connected directly to your computer? No, because your traffic is encapsulated.
ISP of your VPN server? Yes, the ISP will know the destination IP address.

In my opinion, try to use anonymity tools such as Tor or anonymous proxy.

Comment: hm.. some people recommend VPN's over TOR.  dont know about ANON.PROXY.