# Can VPN provider see my data?

Tags: tls, privacy, http, vpn, anonymity

I have a 2 questions:

1. If I use a VPN and I go to any websites via HTTP - does VPN provider will be able to see the traffic? Those. logins, passwords, all the texts that pass through the channel (in the case, if the data is not encrypted).
2. The same option only when using HTTPS (I guess in this case - they can not see).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Will the ISP know what sites I visit if I use a VPN?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/123054/will-the-isp-know-what-sites-i-visit-if-i-use-a-vpn)

Comment: @NeilSmithline: I don't think this is a duplicate. This question asks what the VPN provider can see, the other what the ISP can see.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich good point

Answer (score 17):

1. Yes, the VPN provider is able to see your data. If the data are not encrypted (i.e. HTTPS) the provider will be able to get to the clear text and will also be able to manipulate the data.
2. The usual protections of HTTPS apply, i.e. the provider will see which site you visit but not the clear text data itself because they are encrypted. The provider will also not be able to modify the data undetected. Based on traffic pattern (size, timing...) the provider might still try to narrow down the specific pages you visit on this site.

Comment: Just one clarification: you said "i.e. the provider will see which site you visit but not the clear text data itself " - you mean VPN provider can see IP's/url's/websites, but not Internet provider? (ISP)

Comment: @ideloxew when you use a VPN, you replace the trust you have in your ISP with trust in your VPN service. A VPN sees everything your ISP usually sees.

Comment: @ideloxew: VPN provider can see target IP and hostname with HTTPS (but not the full URL). But the ISP can no longer see it - it sees only that traffic is exchanged with the VPN endpoint.